# Preload video on Android

Tags: android, video, preload

I'm building an interactive movie of some sort , having more video clips that need to load between interactive scenes. The problem is there is a slight delay when starting the video which I believe it could be fixed by preloading the clip right before the previous one finishes. I've tried to start() the video and then stop() it, also seekTo() but i'm no getting the desired result.

Also I need to mention I'm using several VideoViews in the same Activity so I display the appropriate one.

The video files are loaded from the raw folder using the following code

```
    videoView1 = new VideoView(this);
    mediaController1= new MediaController(this);

    mediaController1.setMediaPlayer(videoView1);
    mediaController1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sa1);
    videoView1.setMediaController(mediaController1);
    videoView1.setVideoURI(uri);

    videoView1.requestFocus();

    videoView1.start();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the loading in another thread with using, for example, AsyncTask while the user watches the pervious video.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Thanks, the thing is I already have the videos in the res/raw folder, so no need to download. Basically I need to start the video and stop it after the first frame or something to get it loaded. But seekTo() somehow doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you. I don't exactly know why media player has that kind of delay so my methods to counter it aren't the best. I found a link to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) from another similar question and it seems like that calling prepare() before showing the video helps.